# Pointers and multidimensional arrays

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I want to have an array of `k` 2-element arrays of ints. My code:

```
int **pipe_fd_ptr;
pipe_fd_ptr = malloc(k*sizeof(int*));
for(i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    pipe_fd_ptr = malloc(2*sizeof(int));
}

// this is just for testing
for(i = 0; i<k; i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<2;j++)
        pipe_fd_ptr[i][j] =j;
}
```

I get segfault. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be

```
for(i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    pipe_fd_ptr[ i ] = malloc(2*sizeof(int));
}
```

With `pipe_fd_ptr = malloc(k*sizeof(int*));` you allocated space for k pointers to int
then you iterate trough the array and allocate memory for each pointer with `pipe_fd_ptr[ i ] = malloc(2*sizeof(int));`

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    pipe_fd_ptr[i] = malloc(2*sizeof(int));
}
```